# Examples of Baire Class $\xi+1$ but not $\xi$ functions for each countable ordinal $\xi.$

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

We say that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of **Baire Class $1$** if it is a pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions.

One can generalize the definition above by taking pointwise limit of each 'previous' level(s) to obtain 'next' level.
More precisely,

> For any countable ordinal $\xi\geq 1,$ we say that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$  is of **Baire Class $\xi$** if it is a pointwise limit of a sequence of Baire Class $\zeta$ functions where $\zeta<\xi.$

The generalization covers the case $\xi=1$ as every continuous function is of Baire Class $0.$

When $\xi = 2,$ it is well-known that $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$ is of Baire Class $2$ as it is a pointwise limit of $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $g_n(x) = \max\{0,1-n d(x,K)\}$ and $K$ is a finite collection of rationals. ([extracted from Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Baire_class_2))
Since $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$ is discontinuous everywhere, so it is not of Baire Class $1.$

[This MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614429/examples-of-baire-class-2-functions) also contains other Baire Class $2$ functions.

However, I fail to obtain any Baire Class $3$ function and above.

> *Question*: For each countable ordinal $\xi\geq 3,$ what are some examples of Baire Class $\xi+1$ but not $\xi$ function by using the pointwise limit definition?

Comment: You might have a look, for example, at Section 16 in van Rooij, Schikhof: *A Second Course on Real Functions*. This part of the book is essentially about showing that $\mathscr B_{\xi+1} \setminus \mathscr B_\xi$ is none-empty for a countable ordinal $\xi$.

Comment: Here is also a related posts on Mathematics: [Constructing Baire functions of some class which are not of the previous class](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318749). (With no answers, but at least the comments contain some references.)

Comment: I don't understand the role of $n$ in your definition of Baire class $\xi$.  Do you mean that $f = \lim_n f_n$ pointwise, where each $f_n$ is of Baire class $\xi_n$ for some $\xi_n < \xi$?

Comment: It is possible to explicitly construct Borel sets that are exactly at the level $\xi$ of the Borel hierarchy, but the construction is fairly unenlightening and involves repeated diagonalization over the previous levels: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1614718/84253) for the simplest account I was able to give.  I don't think you should expect much better.

Comment: The buzzword here is "the Baire hierarchy does not collapse".

Comment: @Nate: Must have had a good architect!

Comment: See R. D. Mauldin's 1973 paper [*On Borel measures and Baire's class* $3$](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-039-02/S0002-9939-1973-0316640-8/S0002-9939-1973-0316640-8.pdf) (proof on pp. 310-311) for a "naturally occurring" Baire $3$ function that is not Baire $2$, and see my comments in [this 14 May 2009 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6710566).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A somewhat concrete example of function which is Baire class $\zeta$ but not Baire class $\gamma$ for any $\gamma < \zeta$ is the $\zeta$-th Turing jump. This is essentially the iterated version of Shoenfield's limit lemma. The (iterated) Turing jump naturally gives us a function $J : \{0,1\}^\omega \to \{0,1\}^\omega$, but of course we can embed $\{0,1\}^\omega$ into $\mathbb{R}$ as the Cantor middle set and extend the function, if we prefer to work with $\mathbb{R}$.

Another approach is to piggy-back on the non-collapse of the Borel hierarchy: By the Banach-Lebesgue-Hausdorff theorem, Baire class $\zeta$ and the $\Sigma^0_{1+\zeta}$-measurable functions coincide. So the characteristic function of a $\Sigma^0_{1+\zeta}$-complete set is Baire class $\zeta+1$, but not Baire class $\zeta$.

The example given in the question is of course a special case of the second procedure. A general construction of $\Sigma^0_{1+\zeta}$-complete sets is found eg [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614337/borel-set-that-is-not-countable-union-or-intersection-of-open-or-closed-sets/1614718#1614718)

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, can you elaborate more on it? I understand that Turing jump can be defined inductively. But I fail to see how to obtain a function based on this.

Comment: @Idonknow Does the new sentence clarify this?