# Reference request: Baire class 2 functions

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

There are many articles on Baire 1 functions, but not many on Baire 2 and above. Where can I find a nice comprehensive survey of them?

Comment: Not a survey specifically, but have you seen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614429/examples-of-baire-class-2-functions and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301627/examples-of-baire-class-xi1-but-not-xi-functions-for-each-countable-ordin?rq=1 ?

Comment: I have seen the first but not the second. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find something useful in Kuratowski, Topology, Volume 1 $\S 31$